# Iterative binary search

Tags: code-golf, search

Binary search is an algorithm that looks for an element in a sorted data-structure by constantly dividing the search space in half.

#### [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Binary_search)

> A binary search divides a range of values into halves, and continues to narrow down the field of search until the unknown value is found. It is the classic example of a "divide and conquer" algorithm.

#### [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

> In computer science, a binary search or half-interval search algorithm finds the position of a target value within a sorted array. The binary search algorithm can be classified as a dichotomic divide-and-conquer search algorithm and executes in logarithmic time.

---

Smallest # of bytes wins

#### Clarifications

- Example of calling the function/lambda/macro should be included, but don't count those chars!
- Output should be `> -1` if found, and `<=-1` otherwise
- `import binary_search` (20 bytes) DOES NOT count!
- Implementation should run in O(log n), as algorithm dictates

Also see the [code-golf StackExchange FAQ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info).

#### Example

```
> binary_search([1,3,5,6,7,8,8,10], 5);
4
> binary_search([1,3,5,6,7,8,8,10], 543);
-1
```

Comment: Does our implementation have to be exactly as binary search does it? Does is have to be logarithmic time?

Comment: Can the list have repeats? Are the entries whole numbers? You should give an example that doesn't have all consecutive values.

Comment: @xnor: Thanks for your comments, clarified.

Comment: Regarding your comments on some of the answers: 1. That's not a FAQ; it's the code-golf tag wiki. Also, there are two ordered lists on that page, and both have a 5th item. 2. *Have built-in-to-some-languages solutions excluded* is a suggestion that **you** exclude built-ins when writing up your challenge. That's all it is: a suggestion, not a rule. Built-ins are not forbidden by default, and the second revision of your question doesn't include the word *implementation*.

Comment: 3. Last but not least, please consider using less exclamation points, less bold text and a different tone when dealing with submissions to your challenge. It's a little off-putting, and certainly no incentive to participate in one of your challenges.

Comment: Why should the search be iterative ?

Answer (score 2):

#### JavaScript (94 bytes)

```
(a,e)=>{u=a.length,m=0;for(l=0;l<=u;)e>a[m=(l+u)>>1]?l=m+1:u=e==a[m]?-2:m-1;return u==-2?m:-1}
```

Expanded out a little so you can see what's going on:

```
function binary_search(array, elem) {
    let u = array.length, m;
    for (let l = 0; l <= u;)
        if (elem > array[(m = (l + u) >> 1)]) l = m + 1;
        else u = (elem == array[m]) ? -2 : m - 1;
    return (u == -2) ? m : -1;
}
```

Example usage:

```
> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
> binary_search(a, 5)
4
> binary_search(a, 15)
-1
```

Answer (score 2):

## C – 119 <s>115</s> bytes

Iterative solution at 119 bytes:

```
f(a,x,l,h)int*a,x,l,h;{while(l<h){int m=(h+l)/2;if(a[m]>x)h=m;else if(a[m]<x)l=m+1;else return m;}return a[l]==x?l:-1;}
```

Recursive solution at 115 bytes:

```
f(a,x,l,h)int*a,x,l,h;{if(l==h)return a[l]==x?l:-1;int m=(h+l)/2;return a[m]>x?f(a,x,l,m):(a[m]<x?f(a,x,m+1,h):m);}
```

You can precede with `int`  to prevent compiler warnings or if you're using `gcc` compile with `-Wno-implicit-int`. Sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>

f(a,x,l,h)int*a,x,l,h;{while(l<h){int m=(h+l)/2;if(a[m]>x)h=m;else if(a[m]<x)l=m+1;else return m;}return a[l]==x?l:-1;}

int main()
{
    int x, a[] = {-10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10};

    for (x = -15; x <= 15; x++)
        printf("%d\t%d\n", x, f(a, x, 0, 10));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `-Wno-implicit-int` is our friend :) - Nice little solution you've written, but unfortunately it's recursive… if you get the chance an iterative equivalent would be great! - Otherwise I'll have to 1 up you with a C solution of my own :3

Comment: @AT – Added at a penalty of 4 additional bytes!

Comment: Looking good! - +1 - Though that initialization is a bit weird, I feel that a swap to C++ would save 4 bytes right off the bat :O

Answer (score 2):

## Python 112 bytes

```
def b(A,k):
 l,h=0,len(A)
 while l<h:
  m=(l+h)/2
  if A[m]>k:h=m
  elif A[m]<k:l=m+1
  else:return m
 return -1
```

**Example:**

`print b([1,3,5,6,7,8,8,10], 5)`

`2`

Comment: Rather neat! - I keep trying to improve it, but haven't saved a character yet `>.<` - +1

Answer (score 1):

### [AutoIt](http://autoitscript.com/forum), 92 bytes

This function binary searches an array in-memory and replaces it with an integer holding the index (or -1 if not found). Array needs to be sorted to work with the binary search:

```
#include <Array.au3>
Func b(ByRef $a,$n)
_ArraySort($a)
$a=_ArrayBinarySearch($a,$n)
EndFunc
```

Testing:

```
Local $a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b($a,5)
ConsoleWrite($a & @LF)
```

Output: `4`

Comment: I see no implementation! - See 5 in this site's FAQ. Also I've updated the question to [more] explicitly say that **`import binary_search` doesn't count**!!!

Comment: [kaspersky declares autoit as a trojan](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/111156-kaspersky-and-autoit/) unfortunately for developers

Answer (score 1):

## C++14, <s>87</s> 85 bytes

```c
#include<algorithm>
[](int i,auto v){return std::binary_search(begin(v),end(v),i)-1;}
```

Assumes a sorted data structure which has iterators as input.

**Example:**

```c
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>

auto f = [](int i, auto v){ return std::binary_search(begin(v), end(v), i) - 1; };

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    
    std::cout << f(3, v);
}
```

Comment: I see no implementation! - See 5 in this site's FAQ. Also I've updated the question to [more] explicitly say that **`import binary_search` doesn't count**!!!

Answer (score 1):

## Prolog, 146 bytes

I made the assumption that a program returning easy to understand truthy/falsy values is OK, as adding code just to return -1/1 instead of true/false in a code-golf challenge seems counter-productive.
So the program returns **true** if the value is present in the list, otherwise **false**.

```
s(F,S,L):-append(F,S,L),length(F,G),length(S,T),T>=G,T-G<2.
c(L,X):-s(_,[X|_],L).
c(L,X):-s(_,[M|T],L),X>M,c(T,X).
c(L,X):-s(F,[_|_],L),c(F,X).
```

**How it works**

```
s(F,S,L):-append(F,S,L),length(F,G),length(S,T),T>=G,T-G<2.
```

Helper function that takes the list **L** and splits it in the middle into the lists **F** and **S** where **F** is the lower part of the list.
If **L** has an odd number of elements, **S** is one element larger than **F**.

```
c(L,X):-s(_,[X|_],L).
```

Succeeds if the sought after element **X** is in the middle of list **L**.

```
c(L,X):-s(_,[M|T],L),X>M,c(T,X).
```

Checks for **X** in the higher part of the list if **X** is bigger than the middle element of list **L**.

```
c(L,X):-s(F,[_|_],L),c(F,X).
```

Checks for **X** in the lower part of the list if **X** is smaller than the middle element of list **L**.
As the previous predicates are checked first we can save a few bytes by not doing a comparison here.
**Examples:**

```
> c([1,3,5,6,7,8,8,10],5).
true

> c([1,3,5,6,7,8,8,10],543).
false
```

Comment: Nice one. Sure, happy to relax the `-1` condition. Haven't seen Prolog since college! :P

Answer (score 1):

### Common Lisp, <s>142</s> 143 bytes

*Having seen some of the comments about recursive vs iterative, I'd point out that in any implementation with tail-call optimization, the second (original) solution* is *iterative.*

#### pure iterative, with `do` loop (143):

```
(lambda(a e)(do((l 0)(h(length a)))((<= h l)-1)(let*((m(ash(+ h l)-1))(x(aref a m)))(if(= x e)(return m)(if(< e x)(setf h m)(setf l(1+ m)))))))
```

```
(lambda (a e)
    (do ((l 0)
         (h (length a)))
        ((<= h l) -1)
      (let* ((m (ash (+ h l) -1))
             (x (aref a m)))
        (if (= x e)
            (return m)
            (if (< e x)
                (setf h m)
                (setf l (1+ m)))))))
```

#### recursive (142)

```
(defun b(a e &optional(l 0)(h(length a)))(if(<= h l)-1(let*((m(ash(+ h l)-1))(x(aref a m)))(if(= x e)m(if(< e x)(b a e l m)(b a e(1+ m)h))))))
```

```
(defun b (a e &optional (l 0) (h (length a)))
  (if (<= h l) -1
      (let* ((m (ash (+ h l) -1))
             (x (aref a m)))
        (if (= x e) m
            (if (< e x)
                (b a e l m)
                (b a e (1+ m) h))))))
```

```
CL-USER> (loop with array = #(1 3 5 6 7 8 8 10)
            for element in '(1 7 5 3 2 4 6)
            collect (b array element))
(0 4 2 1 -1 -1 3)
```

Comment: Nice work, haven't seen Lisp in ages! - Also find it amusing that the iterative vs recursive is 1 character apart… +1